# django https + CSRF

Tags: django, https, nginx, csrf

I'm trying to setup django site work ower https with csrf protection. It work on nginx server.

nginx works on https and my django app succesful serve GET requests. when i try to make post request it's fail with

```
Forbidden (403)

CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

CSRF cookie not set.
```

I set

```
fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
```

in settings.py

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

but no results. Is any ideas?

**UPDATE!**
Now i try to work with my django app ower http with nginx and i have the same problem, so https does not make a sense.
How can I start it work with nginx ower http and use csrf protection?

**UPDATE! AND SOLUTION!**
ensure_csrf_cookie - decorator to force sending csrf token to requested page.
it helps me because my app works mostly with ajax POST and GET, which don't use the  tags.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need either the csrf tag inside your html template,

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
```

or a decorator above your view method ...

```
@csrf_protect
def my_view(request):
```

Read here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/

Comment: thanks for answer but i'm already do that. my django dev server works fine.